# How to store git repo to a specific path in node setup in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-agent

How to checkout to a specific path in jenkins node setup. I am using ubuntu14.04 and go language.

What I have followed is below:

Created a jenkins user in my slave machine and created folder called jenkins_slave

so, my pwd is `/home/jenkins/jenkins_slave`. I have provided this in my node configuration in Jenkins master. My GOPATH is set to `/home/jenkins/jenkins_slave/go`.

When I execute my build step, jenkins is cloning my master branch git repo into `/home/jenkins/jenkins_slave/workspace/pipeline` (pipeline is my job name).. But what I am looking is my git repo should be checkout to a custom path like `/home/jenkins/jenkins_slave/go/src/github.com/username/repository`.

What are all the options to keep my git code into the above repository?

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your job to use custom workspace - in the job configuration under restrict where this job can run you have an advance button on the right, click on it and then you'll see the custom workspace option.

If it's a maven project you have in the advance section "use custom workspace"

Your custom workspace should be : go/src/github.com/username/repository

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you are cloning your repo using git under Source Code Management then you can clone your repo to specified directory using below:

Under Additional Behaviours : Check out to sub directory

[image]

URL of the GIT plugin:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin

If you are doing it in command line then you can do like below:

```
git clone <git_repo> /home/jenkins/jenkins_slave/go/src/github.com/username/repository
```

Comment: It's not working. My setup is below: I am using Jenkins2.0 version Step 1 - I have created node (slave) - In the salve `remote root directory` I have given `/home/jenkins/jenkins_slave'. Step 2 - In my master jenkins job (pipeline) I have given `/go/src/github.com/reponame`.. So, when I execute my build jenkins in cloning into /home/jenkins/jenkins_slave/workspace/pipeline(job name).. But for me, it has to go to /home/jenkins/jenkins_slave/workspace/pipeline/go/src/reponame/username. My GOPATH is set to `/home/jenkins/jenkins_slave/workspace/pipeline/go`. Looking for help.. Thanks